# Encrypting/decrypting with RSA Bouncy Castle not working properly

Tags: java, encryption, rsa, bouncycastle

I'm trying to encryt/decrypt using RSAEngine library at bouncy castle, with a 2048 bit length key. I'm able to create the keys, store in different files and get from the files, but when I decrypt an image it makes something that I don't know that the file decrypted is not shown correctly.Files are created correctly,and I think the problem is at processBlock method while encrypting and/or decrypting.The code is the following to encrypt:

```
InputStream clearTextFile;
    FileOutputStream textFileProcessed=new FileOutputStream(fileName);
            //getKey is a method I implemented and works correctly
    RSAKeyParameters key=getKey(keyFileName);
    RSAEngine rsaEngine=new RSAEngine();
    rsaEngine.init(true,key);           
    clearTextFile=new FileInputStream(nameClearTextFile);
    byte[] bytesReaded;
    int nBytesReaded;
    int inputBlockSize=rsaEngine.getInputBlockSize();
    do
    {
        bytesReaded = new byte[inputBlockSize];
        nBytesReaded=clearTextFile.read(bytesReaded);
        if(nBytesReaded>-1)
        {       //This is for the last block if it's not 256 byte length
            if(nBytesReaded<inputBlockSize)
            {
                byte[] temp=new byte[nBytesReaded];
                for(int i=0;i<nBytesReaded;i++)
                {
                    temp[i]=bytesReaded[i];
                }
                byte[] encryptedText=rsaEngine.processBlock(temp,0,nBytesReaded);
                textFileProcessed.write(encryptedText);
            }
            else
            {
                byte[] encryptedText=rsaEngine.processBlock(bytesReaded,0,inputBlockSize);
                textFileProcessed.write(encryptedText); 
            }
        }
    }while(nBytesReaded>-1);
    textFileProcessed.flush();
    textFileProcessed.close();
    textFileProcessed.close();
```

And to decrypt:

```
InputStream encryptedTextFile=new FileInputStream(nameOfFile);
    OutputStream decryptedTextFile=new FileOutputStream(nameOfFile);
    RSAKeyParameters key=getKey(nameKeyFile);
    RSAEngine rsaEngine=new RSAEngine();
    rsaEngine.init(false,key);
    byte[] bytesReaded;
    int nBytesReaded;
    int inputBlockSize=rsaEngine.getInputBlockSize();
    do
    {
        bytesLeidos = new byte[inputBlockSize];
        nBytesReaded=encryptedTextFile.read(bytesReaded);
        if(nBytesReaded>-1)
        {
                byte[] decryptedText=rsaEngine.processBlock(bytesReaded,0,inputBlockSize);          
                decryptedTextFile.write(decryptedText);                 
        }
    }while(nBytesReaded>-1);
    decryptedTextFile.flush();
    decryptedTextFile.close();
    encryptedTextFile.close();
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please simplify your code to remove all the file reading/writing. That will help isolate if the problem is the crypto or the IO work. Try to create a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) - it's helpful for us and it's a great way to solve problems for yourself.

Comment: The thing is that I believe that the mistake is at encypting or decrypting,the error may resides at saving the bytes in the file or reading from there.I don't know it it's this way, but it may be saving information about the data and that is the real problem

Comment: The reason I suggested simplification is to discover where the problem lies. Remove the IO operations and you'll determine if your cryptography is at fault. If it isn't, then it's probably the IO operations. This is a basic debugging principle.

Comment: So replace the file streams with byte streams. Initialize the input for encryption with "Javier". Encrypt and decrypt and see if you get your name back. Similarly, you could take out the encrypt and decrypt parts and see if the files are getting written and read correctly. Divide and conquer.

Comment: That code doesn't even compile.

Comment: can I know where can I get example in this? :)

Answer (score 2):

RSAEngine does not add padding, you will lose any leading zeros in your data blocks as a result. You need to use one of the encoding modes available as well.

I'd recommend using a symmetric key algorithm as well and just using RSA to encrypt the symmetric key. It will be a lot faster, and depending on your data, safer as well.

Regards,

David

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to change this line:

```
   if(nBytesReaded>1)
```

to this

```
   if(nBytesReaded>-1)
```

And change this in the decypt part, maybe:

```
rsaEngine.init(false,clave);
```

to this

```
rsaEngine.init(false,key);
```

But there may be more. You aren't encrypting the whole input if the last block isn't full size.

Comment: Thanks.I din't see the first one. The second one was a mistake when translating. Apparently it takes the whole input because in a 21KB file size and taking the getInputBlockSize the last one it's 82 byte length, and this is the reason I created temp.After processing RSAEngine adds a padding or something like that if I'm not wrong. Though I repaired the mistakes the problem remains